# MVVM Listbox ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to fire the command by right clicking and selecting the context menu on wpf mmv light app. The listbox is made up of a datatemplte.

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu Width="150" >
         <MenuItem Header="Move to holiday">
              <MenuItem.Icon>
               <TextBlock FontFamily="/BoonManager;component/Fonts/seguisym.ttf#Segoe UI Symbol" Text="&#x1f304;" />
              </MenuItem.Icon>
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                  <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.ComMoveToHoliday ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  </MenuItem>
       </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

I have also tried using this

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

but no luck. Thanks Scott

**Update
I have code running just above the ContextMenu that runs fine.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.ComShowPerson, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="Expected" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So it must be the contextMenu that is blocking this.

Comment: why not use a command on the menu item itself ?

Comment: thanks. Is the command not already on the menu item? Its nested inside.

Comment: clicking the context menu item didn't work for you ? or you had problems with the DataContext ?

Comment: Clicking the context item should fire the command in the model but its not.

Comment: your command is in the DataContext of the list box ?

Comment: No. Datacontext of the viewmodel. I tried to point it to the root of the window. i.e. Command="{Binding DataContext.ComMoveToHoliday ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69401/discussion-between-stsur-and-scottsanpedro).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to track down an answer from this link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80632/WPF-Context-Menu-on-List-Item
Worked great. Thanks for any help.Appreciated. Scott

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like that instead

```
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding FullPathCommand}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: No. still not firing. Maybe the issue is complicated by the datatemplate? Though I have similar code  that works above the contextmenu fine. I will add it to the original question.Thanks for your help.